# Add two dictionaries in python and subtract result from another

Tags: python

I have three dictionaries:

```
X = {'a':2, 'b':3,'e':4}

Y = {'c':3, 'b':4,'a':5, 'd':7}

Z = {'c':8, 'b':7,'a':9, 'e':10,'f':10}
```

I want to add elements of X and Y if they are present in both dicts and then subtract them from z i.e. `Z-X+Y`

How can I do that ?

expected result:

```
res = {'a':2,'b':0,'c':5,'d':7,'e':6,'f':10}
```

What I tried:

```
from collections import Counter
xy = Counter(X) + Counter(Y)
res = Counter(Z) - xy
```

which return:

```
Counter({'c': 5, 'a': 2, 'e': 6, 'f': 10})
```

as you can see `b` and `d` are missing from my attempt

Comment: You said you want to subtract `X+Y` from `Z`, but your expected result has `'d': 7` instead of `'d': -7`; is that a typo, or is your explanation (or am I) missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your expected result is actually an operation of symmetric difference in terms of sets, but since `collections.Counter` doesn't support such an operation, you can emulate it with:

```
xy = Counter(X) + Counter(Y)
z = Counter(Z)
res = z - xy | xy - z
```

`res` becomes:

```
Counter({'f': 10, 'd': 7, 'e': 6, 'c': 5, 'a': 2})
```

But if you do want keys with value of `0`, which `Counter` would hide from its output, you would have to iterate through a union of the keys of the 3 dicts:

```
{k: res.get(k, 0) for k in {*X, *Y, *Z}}
```

This returns:

```
{'a': 2, 'd': 7, 'e': 6, 'b': 0, 'f': 10, 'c': 5}
```